# "Fusing" 2 mutexing threads into 1 for execution on single core

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

this
is a weird question, so Ill try to provide long explanation.
   Lets say that you are running on a single core machine. And you have 2 threads, lets say classic producer consumer problem with mutexes. Now Im wondering when running on a single core machine(so 1 core no HT):
Is there a way in C++ to fuse the execution of those 2 threads into one, so that mutex can be implemented as a simple int store/load operation, instead of mutexing. 
For example would this work:
producer code in the unified thread  can be just putting stuff into circular buffer and consumer code will just read from the buffer if the current buffer_idx is higher than processed_idx.

I know this seems like a stupid question, but tbh a lot of embedded stuff is still 1 core.
For simplicity assume that both threads are of form

```
while(! shutdown)
{
//...
}
```

Would just putting both while bodies  in a big while work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can put both producer and consumer in one thread. But what for? Their store/load operations will be sequentially executed. There will be always "peace" between them (excluding unexpected situations). For every producer store operation there will be consumer load operation (if there is no conditional statement, if yes than producer will stop and wait until consumer code will load all stuff, and then loop starts again). IMO, using such model you can only describe a small part of real world situations in your code.

EDIT: Even if you are on single core machine, spliting your logic into several threads will lead you to better performance than making all stuff in one thread. For example, while producer will creating some stuff, your consumer will do nothing even if there is some stuff stored, it's loos of time. Imagine, after consumer load stuff, he have to give stuff to another element of your logic, and if there are a lot of other elements, standing after consumer, they all be waiting for only one logic element -- producer, and then wait for consumer, etc. Time taked by processor to switch between threads in the most times is less than time needed to produce or consume stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since by having one infinite loops after another means that one will never get executed, Let's assume we have "magical" GOTO statements, which jumps us to the right place every time. Then yes, putting the two while loops together might work since the GOTO is essentially a monitor here though it may not be what you want.

On the other hand, assume the loops terminates at the right time. Fusing two threads (without slicing CPU time) into one essentially nullifies your initial problem. There would not be any need of mutex's, for there is nothing to exclude instead of the running process itself.

Also to consider is that single-core systems also have concurrency problem, and they run multiple threads in time slices to simulate (in a way) how multi-core systems work; the same multexing stuff should be directly transferable.

Comment: notice "both while *bodies* ", i would have while () {whilebody1 whilebody2}

Comment: even in that case, the consumer can still wait indefinitely because there's no producer putting stuff into the buffer, depending on the actual code logic. So, assuming each part does move on eventually, consumer and producer will not need additional mutex's because they will run sequentially in a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to be just as careful. It can't run both threads at the same time but with premptive multitasking your code can be interrupted and the other thread run at any point so you still need to lock things just as much in general.

One common thing to do is to make the "store in queue" operation on the first thread instead call the "process from queue" function in the other thread directly (and only have one thread). It's possible, with the right design to make code that runs single threaded on a single core, and multithreaded if you have more than one core. That avoids having to lock when you only have one core.

Answer (score 0):

Such 'unprotected' queues are common on embedded stuff, eg. whe communicating between threads and an interrupt driver.  Such drivers cannot use a mutex at all, (though they can usually signal a semaphore to make a thread ready, eg. when a completed protocol packet has been shoved onto such an unprotected queue).  Driver comms have the advantage of one end being absolutely sure that the other end cannot interrupt it - the driver cannot be interrupted by the thread.  That makes it fairly easy to ensure that indexes/pointers are updated in a 'safe' order.

Between two threads, however, things get more difficult.  Either end can interrupted by the other at any point while the indexes/pointers are being manipulated.  I always lock such queues with a mutex, (the inter-thread queues I use for emebedded comms have no internal storage anyway - the messages themselves have an internal forward link, which makes lock-free queues even more awkward).

Comment: using c++11 <atomic> to make buff_idx atomic it should be pretty easy to ensure seq consistency. I guess.  :)